# Derby Eclipse classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I'm new at Derby+Eclipse and trying to use it on my Mac OS. I've downloaded db-derby-10.8.3.0-bin zip file from http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html , extracted it and added it to CLASSPATH via eclipse properties->java build path. Now when I try 
`java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo` in my terminal it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/tools/sysinfo
```

When I try echo $CLASSPATH there is an empty string.
I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse `Java Build Path` just sets the class path for compiling and running the project from within Eclipse. It does **not** set the system CLASSPATH, you will have to set that separately outside of Eclipse.